# CICLO HREF JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

Necesito un ciclo en jquery donde me este referenciando distintas páginas 
y la variable se este incrementando.

Ejemplo

```
setTimeout(function(){
<?php
$b=1;
?>

   location.href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b?>"

 <?php $B++?>
    } , 2000); 
</script>
```

lo he intentado así pero no incrementa solo muestra siempre la misma página.

GRACIAS.

Comment: Re-formula la pregunta que no está claro lo que quieres hacer, o aporta más datos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas volviendo a inicializar la variable a 1 en cada recarga de pagina en la función setTimeout.

Una mejor versión seria

```
setTimeout(function(){

  <?php
    if ($_GET['page']){
      $b=1;
    } else {
      $b = (int)($_GET['page']) + 1;
    }
  ?>

  location.href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b?>"


} , 2000);
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero no funciono talvez no estoy siendo muy claro, la variable de $b forma el total de las paginas, cuando doy click dentro del primer boton, page obtiene el valor de 1 podrias pasarme tu correo para mostrarte mas detalladamente amigo, me ayudarias bastante! MIL GRACIAS  @joel Ibaceta

Comment: No me queda claro el motivo del setTimeout lo que logra este código es redireccionar de forma indefinida cada 2 segundos

Comment: Mira lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla ya paginada, y necesito un ciclo que este mostrando los registros cada  determinado tiempo por eso el settimeout en mi caso la variable $b es la que se encarga de crear los botones que contienen el href dependiendo los registros se van creando mas botones, al presionar uno de estos se pasa el valor a la variable page @Joel Ibaceta

Comment: El comentario de @JoelIbaceta es correcto. Cuando se recarga la página, se vuelve a generar el Javascript usando PHP, y el valor de la variable `$b` es 1, no cambia. Por eso te propone enviar el valor de `$b` por parametro GET, para que se pueda "recordar" al volver a cambiar la página